# Best way to share code between multiple MVC applications and deploy different versions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture

We currently have a single database with users, customers, products and orders logically separated by schemas. We then have several MVC.net applications accessing the database via their own BLLs. Each of these applications have their own functionality and share some aspects with some/all of the other applications.

Currently, some code is duplicated in these BLLs and it's a bit of a mess to maintain. It does however, allow us to develop features quickly and deploy each application independently (assuming on major database work here).

We have started to develop a single access layer, properly separated out that sits above the database and is used by all of our MVC.net applications. Logically this makes sense as we can now share code between our applications. For example, application A can retrieve a customer record in the same way as application B. The issue comes when we want to deploy an application, we wouldn't be able to deploy one application, we'd need to deploy them all.

What other architectural approaches could we consider that would allow us to share code between our applications and deploy those applications independently?

Comment: What is a BLL, did you mistype a DLL (Assembly)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips BLL is an abbreviation for Business Logic Layer

Comment: have you consider create a web api?

Answer (score 2):

A common solution is to factor out services (based on an arbitrary communication layer REST, WCF, Message Bus, your choice with versioning) and deploy these services to your infrastructure as standalone services.

Now you can evolve, scale and deploy your services independently of the consumers. Instead of deploying all applications you now only have to deploy the changed services (side-by-side with the old ones) and the new application.

This adds quite a lot of complexity around service versioning, configuration management, integration testing, a little communication overhead etc. So you have to balance the pros and cons. There are quite a bunch of articles on the net how to build such an architecture.